# Rmarkdown with Rstudio doesn't show the changes

Tags: yaml, rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm using RStudio to produce an R usage manual. However, after making changes to YAML when I run Build Book (bookdown :: pdf_book) the output does not show the changes. In fact, the output is leaving with the date of the 2020/01/20.

My YAML before the change:

```
---
title: "Manual de Econometria com R"
subtitle: "Centro de Ciências Sociais Aplicadas \nUniversidade Federal da Paraíba \nParaíba, Brasil"
author: "Alexandre Loures"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: bookdown::gitbook
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
cover-image: images/logo-R.png
bibliography: [econometrics.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
---
```

My YAML after change:

```
---
title: "Manual de Econometria com R"
subtitle: "Programa de Pós-Graduação em Economia \nCentro de Ciências Sociais Aplicadas \nUniversidade Federal da Paraíba \nJoão Pessoa, Paraíba, Brasil"
author: "Alexandre Loures"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: bookdown::gitbook
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
cover-image: images/logo-R.png
bibliography: [econometrics.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
---
```

I don't know if it's related to the fact that I uninstalled Miktex and then installed Miktex again.

Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: silly question, but have you run the entire .rmd again rather than using the cache from the last full run script?

Comment: Hello @oaxacamatt! Yes, I ran the whole .rmd again. But I managed to solve it by updating all R packages and all Miktex packages.

Comment: Oh, I always have problems with older packages. Good to know.

Comment: Hi @oaxacamatt! I don't like to update for this reason, as it always causes conflict. But as I had uninstalled and reinstalled Miktex I thought about the possibility that there was a problem due to outdated packages of both R and Miktex. So I updated all the R and Miktex packages and the problem was solved.

Comment: Hi Alex, I completely understand. Updating is a very delicate process.  Do you know if one can turn off R updates for *only* one package, similar to Linux having that ability?